# Can I send a transaction in the current slot

Tags: transactions, send-transaction

I want to send a transaction in the current slot. The way I am doing this is by getting the latest processed blockhash and then adding it in my transaction and sending it to the current leader in bursts of 2-3 using QUIC protocol (not using the slower RPC method).

still I see most of the transactions landing in 2 slots ahead of the targeted slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not guaranteed to get into the same slot, you can see the current average slot latency here: https://www.validators.app/ping-thing

Also i think the leader tpu accepts incoming transactions stake weighted using quic.

Answer (score 1):

The best guarantee that a transaction lands in a slot is to be the validator that proposes the block. Even then, there's a chance that it doesn't get accepted by the network!

Comment: I am talking about the average user. say an MEV seeker